Resource not found - LinkedIn Ads Reporting API
Continually getting errors using LinkedIn API.
async function fetchAdData(access_token) {
    const headers = { 
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`, 
        'Linkedin-Version': '202401',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
    };
    
    const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics';

    const data = {
        q: 'analytics',
        timeGranularity: 'ALL',
        dateRange: {
            start: {
                year: 2021,
                month: 1,
                day: 1
            }
        },
        facets: ['INDUSTRY'] // Include necessary facet(s) as per API requirements
    };

    let response;
    try {
        response = await axios.post(url, data, { headers });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error details:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        if (error.response && error.response.data.errorDetails && error.response.data.errorDetails.inputErrors) {
            error.response.data.errorDetails.inputErrors.forEach(err => {
                console.error("Input error code:", err.code);
                console.error("Input error path:", err.input.inputPath);
            });
        }
    }
}

Errors:
Error details: {
  status: 404,
  code: 'RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND',
  message: 'No virtual resource found'
}

With the updates to the API, asking if there is something that is missing?
Tried various version of pinging Linkedin API to get advertising data.

const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics';
issted of this
const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2';
paste this url and try this
